# Use 'if' but no 'else' to accomplish this

Tags: python, if-statement

newbie here again.  I am trying to accomplish the following question but stuck on the condition in bold:

- get user input in variable: `about_pet`
- using a series of if statements respond with appropriate conversation
- check if "dog" is in the string about_pet (sample reply "Ah, a dog")
- check if "cat" is in the string about_pet
- **check if 1 or more animal is in string about_pet**
- no need for else's
- finish with thanking for the story

Code I wrote:

```
about_pet = input("Enter a sentence about a pet: ")

if 'dog' in about_pet.lower():
    print ("Ah, a dog")
if 'cat' in about_pet.lower():
    print ("Ah, a cat")
elif 'dog, cat' in about_pet.lower():
      print ("Ah, there is one or more pet")

print("Thank you for your story")
```

I tried few other ways but stuck.  Could you help me to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Thank you all for help!  I dug up the course forum and seems to me the instructor is pitching to use boolean.  i.e 'dog' in about_pet.lower() == True to verify if the input statement has more than one pet or not.  I am stuck here how to utilize boolean to check the input statement.

Thank you all again for help!

Comment: not that you'll never enter in the elif condition if there's a cat in the sentence.

Comment: try `all(x in about_pet for x in ['dog','cat'])`

Comment: You should include the "if ('dog' in about_pet.lower( )) and ('cat' in about_pet.lower()):" statement before. And correct the identation.

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'dog' in about_pet.lower():
print ("Ah, a dog")
if 'cat' in about_pet.lower():
    print ("Ah, a cat")
if 'dog' in about_pet.lower() or 'cat' in about_pet.lower():
      print ("Ah, there is one or more pets")
```

Comment: No, I mean 'or'. The question says 1 or more.

Comment: I copied the poster's original verbiage. The wording is not a concern to me. Yes, technically the wording "there is more than one pet" is not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
elif 'dog, cat' in about_pet.lower():
    print ("Ah, there is more than one pet")
```

change above condition to below mentioned condition:

```
if 'dog' in about_pet.lower() or 'cat' in about_pet.lower():
    print ("Ah, there is more than one pet")
```

Comment: well looking at the statement "if 1 or more animal", I don't think so

Comment: It should be and instead of or.

Comment: am not getting, why "and"
@Diego can you elaborate

Comment: Because of the print statement. But if the ideia is to verify if at least one of the animals is on the list, you are correct.

Comment: I retract my objection: The requirements agree with you, it's OP's print that does not.

Answer (score 1):

What about this simple logic using 2 flags and condition optimizing (okay there's a `else` but that just saves some tests, coding without `else` is an unjustified constraint):

```
about_pet = about_pet.lower()
has_dog = 'dog' in about_pet
has_cat = 'cat' in about_pet

if has_dog:
    if has_cat:
        print ("Ah, there is more than one pet")
    else:
        print ("Ah, a dog")
elif has_cat:
    print ("Ah, a cat")
```

note that word-boundary regexes would be better to avoid matching in words (like "caterpillar"):

```
import re

has_dog = re.search(r'\bdog\b',about_pet,re.IGNORECASE) # note: raw prefix before \b word boundary!
has_cat = re.search(r'\bcat\b',about_pet,re.IGNORECASE)
```

the rest of the tests remain the same

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to make a list in the scenario where they have more than 1 pets.

```
def pet_convo():
    about_pet=input('What pets do you have? ')
    myList = about_pet.split(',')
    if len(myList)>1:
        print('Ah, you have many animals')
    elif 'cat' in about_pet.lower():
        print("Ah, a cat")
    elif 'dog' in about_pet.lower():
        print('Ah, a dog')
    print('Thank you for your story')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember about the right position ;)

```
about_pet = input("Enter a sentence about a pet: ")
if "cat" in about_pet and "dog" in about_pet:
    print("Ah! there is one or more pet!")
elif "cat" in about_pet:
    print("Ah! a cat ")
elif "dog" in about_pet:
    print("Oh! a dog ")
print("Thank you for your story!")
```

Comment: Reordering of the if statements means you will land on the "cat" and "dog" in about_pet branch if it occurs and do not accidentally go to the case where only "cat" or "dog" is in the about_pet